# Objc Equivalent of STFail but stopping the test

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

i'm looking for equivalent of STAssertTrue, STAssertFail...

but they can stop the test when it's wrong (like in Java).

They have something like that in objc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`raiseAfterFailure` method of SenTestCase](https://github.com/jy/SenTestingKit/blob/master/SenTestCase.h#L146).  For example in the following test method, "EPIC FAIL" will never happen.

```
- (void)testFailing
{
    [self raiseAfterFailure];

    STFail(@"FAIL");
    STFail(@"EPIC FAIL!");
}
```

Comment: this worked really well for getting the debugger to break on a failed test. i called `raiseAfterFailure` in `-setUp` and set a breakpoint on all objc exceptions.